# How can I adjust my data in a text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Python to help me organize my data. Specifically, I'm trying to figure out how I can adjust onset times, and separate correct and incorrect responses using Python.

For example my experiment results for each subject is stored in a text file (sub001.txt).[here is one subject file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8yk2c53700nl9z/sub001.txt?dl=0).

The 1st column corresponds to the onset time(in seconds).
The 2nd column corresponds to the response time (in
ms).
The 3rd column corresponds to whether or not the response was
correct (0: incorrect, 1: correct).

I am trying to write a program to read this file, then do the following:

**a.** Subtract 10s from all onset times.
**b.** Separate the files associated with correct and incorrect responses so that I can run statistics on those separately.

So I will have 2 files for one subject (sub001_correct.txt and sub001_incorrect.txt). Each file should contain two columns. The first column should contain the corrected onset
times (from a. above). The second column should contain the
response time.

I tried looking at other questions and answers but haven't had much luck.

Comment: Hi, Jissel. Have you written any code yet? What does it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what you want:

```
f = open('sub001.txt', 'r')
f_correct = open('correct001.txt', 'w')
f_incorrect = open('incorrect001.txt', 'w')


for line in f:
    parts = line.strip().split(' ')
    onset = int(parts[0])
    response = parts[2]
    correctness = parts[4]

    corrected_onset = onset - 10
    if correctness == '1':
        new_entry = str(corrected_onset) + ' ' + response + '\n'
        f_correct.write(new_entry)
    else:
        new_entry = str(corrected_onset) + ' ' + response + '\n'
        f_incorrect.write(new_entry)

f.close()
f_correct.close()
f_incorrect.close()
```

Comment: I get a syntax error and the it highlights the 5 in 3.5.2 in red. Any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't undertand the problem yet. Since I can't find any "5" in the source code above, and I don't assume that you mean the "5" in the Python version string you gave ("3.5.2"), which "5" are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Jissel,

I prefer to use a library called `pandas` to do this kind of manipulation. Here is a script that will do what you want using it.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def parse_file(filepath):
    org_df = pd.read_csv(filepath, delim_whitespace=True, names=['startTime', 'responseTime', 'correct'])
    org_df['startTime'] = org_df['startTime'].subtract(10)
    groups = org_df.group_by('correct')
    for g in groups:
        id = g[0]
        df = g[1]
        if id == 0:
            type = 'incorrect'
        else:
            type = 'correct'
        df[['startTime', 'responseTime']].to_csv(
            os.path.splitext(filepath)[0] + '_' + type + os.path.splitext(filepath)[1], index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_file('F:/sub001.txt')
```

There are three parts:

1. Read in the file:

   `org_df = pd.read_csv(filepath, delim_whitespace=True, names=['startTime', 'responseTime', 'correct'])`

We tell pandas where the file is, that we want to separate columns based on white space and that we want to name our columns `startTime, responseTime` and `correct`

2. Subtract an integer to the `startTime` column:

   'org_df['startTime'] = org_df['startTime'].add(subtract)'

We tell pandas that we want our new `startTime` column to be equal to our old column minus `10`

3. Separate by whether the answer was correct or not:

   `groups = org_df.group_by('correct')
   for g in groups:
       id = g[0]
       df = g[1]
       if id == 0:
           type = 'incorrect'
       else:
           type = 'correct'
       df[['startTime', 'responseTime']].to_csv(
           os.path.splitext(filepath)[0] + '_' + type + os.path.splitext(filepath)[1], index=False)`

Here we tell pandas to separate the data into groups based on the values in the `correct' column. then we examine each group, decide if it s the "correct" or "incorrect" group. and then output the result as CSVs.

Comment: I think Jissel wanted the new startTime to be 10 less than the original one.